# for/if loops and a scope of the variable in python

Tags: python, scope

I am confused about the scope of the variable in python. Here is a toy example of what I am trying to do:

```
a = True
enumerated_set = enumerate(['tic','tac','toe'])
for i,j in enumerated_set:
    if a == True:
        print j
```

The result I get is:

```
tic
tac
toe
```

now,

`print a`

returns

```
`True`
```

and if I ran again

```
for i,j in enumerated_set:
    if a == True:
        print j
```

I get no output.

I am confused... Since globally `a = True`, why during the second loop the print was not executed.

I appreciate your help.

Edit: another example where I am confused

```
y = 'I like this weather'.split()
for item in y:
    for i,j in enumerated_set:
         if a == True: 
             print j
```

also produces no output....

Comment: You would need to re-create your generator created by `enumerate`  every time you want to use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is actually not a problem with your boolean. That is always `True`.

`enumerated_set` is a generator. Once you cycle through it, it is exhausted. You would need to create a new one.

```
In [9]: enumerated_set = enumerate(['tic','tac','toe'])

In [10]: enumerated_set.next()
Out[10]: (0, 'tic')

In [11]: enumerated_set.next()
Out[11]: (1, 'tac')

In [12]: enumerated_set.next()
Out[12]: (2, 'toe')

In [13]: enumerated_set.next()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/<ipython-input-13-7b0a413e4250> in <module>()
----> 1 enumerated_set.next()

StopIteration:
```

Comment: Ohhh, now it makes sense. I was just going of the python documentation and didn't find any mention about it being exhaustive. Thank you!

Comment: @notorckstart: don't forget to accept the answer  ;-) he answered faster then i could comment! ;-)

Comment: It would have to be exhausted, otherwise it would never stop when you loop over it :-) No problem! I think you were thinking about it like being a function call, such as when you loop over a list and it calls the builtin method for looping over it's indexes each time. This is more like a "saved" loop that only evaluates as you ask it each time.

Comment: @DonQuestion, apparently now you have to wait for 10 minutes from the posting time to accept the answer. 
jdi, Thank you for saving my sanity!

Comment: The normal usage for `enumerate` is to call it anew each time you want to loop with index, not to save it to a variable; since the result of `enumerate` can only be used once in most circumstances, there's no point in giving it a name.

Answer (score 1):

This is not due to scope, it is due to the nature of `enumerate`, which creates a *generator*, not a list. Generators are single-use: they pop off elements in sequence, they don't create a list which can be evaluated again. This saves memory.

If you wanted to iterate over enumerated_set twice, you might do this:

`enumerated_set = list(enumerate(['tic','tac','toe']))`

Answer (score 1):

It is nothing to do with the a variable.
You are using an enumerator object,and in the first loop it is gone to its end.
You have to recreate it for the second loop.